# Is it possible to make image centered?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make image centered? SO it will be displayed like the one which is displayed with background-position: center center.

HTML :

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="{img_src}" />  //Lets assume original dimension of image is 1200X700
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {width:500px; height:400px}
.image-container img { max-width:100%; }
```

I want image to fill entire container width and remove the left and right portion of image, so it will be displayed as centered.

Comment: yes possible, but what you want?

Comment: This question is completely vague, it is impossible to answer. _What_ image? In _what_ situation? Using _which_ markup? And _which_ style rules?

Comment: please be more specific about what you want to achieve. share relevant code and make a working example to show us your problem

Comment: I am having problem to center image (using img tag), I want image to cut left and right portion depending on window width.
I know it is possible to make image centered using background-img,position in css but I am having difficulty in making it center using img tag

Comment: Please share your attempt(s), make snippet, add HTML/CSS, we need context

Comment: Without knowing what your code looks like, I'd say either put `<center></center>` tags around your `<img>` tag, or give your image a class and use CSS to center it. This works for horizontal centering. If you're trying to achieve vertical centering as well, I would recommend staying with the background-image instead.

Comment: Without  knowing the rest of the code, you can do something like this: https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score 0):

you can assign `text-align: center` to parent of img

or

use `margin: 0 auto` to img

```css
.one{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
.two img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
</div>

<div class="two">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to set any styles on the `img` .

but instead style it's container using `display:flex` and align the items inside it vertically and horizontally so you will achieve what you want

in the below example i've put the same image in 2 different containers ( first is styled second is not ) to show you the difference

**keep in mind.** that in this example. the image is not shrinked or resized , but instead it has the same width and height ( 1200x700 ) but the parts that don't fit inside the container, are `cut` out.

let me know if this helps

```css
.image-container {
  width:500px; 
  height:400px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x700">
 </div>
 
 <div class="nostyle">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x700">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.image-container img { max-width:60%;margin: auto;} or

.image-container img { max-width:300px;margin: auto;}